# How can i get mouse click event element in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, accessibility

I receive events from clicks with a global monitor in macOS.
The NSEvent give me coordinates but i need to get the UIElement.

Using the accessibility API, i can get the focused element but i need the clicked element which is totaly different. For example, if i click on a textarea, i get a AXTextArea element. If i click on the application taskbar, the focused element remains AXTextArea which make sense. I want the element associated to the mouse event.

I found on the web a method called accessibilityHitTest which is supposed to retrieve the UIElement under a given NSPoint. I always get null so i am not sure this is supposed to work that way.

Maybe there is another function which retrieve the UIElement from a given point in the screen?

Here is what ive tried :

```
NSEvent *event; // My event received from global monitoring
id clickedObject = [self accessibilityHitTest:event.locationInWindow];
//This give me an error because self is not a NSWindow.

NSEvent *event; // My event received from global monitoring
id clickedObject = 
[[NSApp keyWindow] accessibilityHitTest:event.locationInWindow];
//This give me null at every click.
```

Maybe this is not possible but i just which i could get the UIElement under my mouse click and not the focused UIElement.

Comment: Try to hitTest your main View (Window.contentView) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483364-hittest?language=objc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`AXUIElementCopyElementAtPosition()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/1462077-axuielementcopyelementatposition?language=objc) for this. Note that you have to be careful to provide the coordinates in the proper coordinate system. Since the event has no `window` associated with (because it's for a different app), `NSEvent`'s `locationInWindow` uses the Cocoa coordinate system with the origin in the lower-left of the primary display, with `y` increasing in the up direction. `AXUIElementCopyElementAtPosition()` takes coordinates in the Core Graphics coordinate system with the origin in the upper-left of the primary display, with `y` increasing down. Basically, you do:

```
point.y = NSMaxY(NSScreen.screens[0].frame) - point.y;
```

Comment: This is awesome thanks. I am printing with NSLog the uielement and i can see there is a PID value. How can i extract it do you know?

Comment: You can use `AXUIElementGetPid()`.